# c++ using subclass 'type cast' error

Tags: c++, types, casting

I got a abstract baseclass "Furniture" with 1 subclass "Bookcase".

In a handler.cpp I created double pointer; Furniture** furnitures. So when I want to add stuff, i can use something like this;

```
void FurnitureHandler::addBookcase(string name, float price, int stock, string material, float height)
{
    this->furniture[this->nrOfFurniture] = new Bookcase(name, price, stock, material, height);
    this->nrOfFurniture++;
}
```

However, "new" is highlighted and I get 'error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'Bookcase *' to 'Furniture *' exists, but is inaccessible'. What do I have to do to make it work?

codes;

```
#ifndef __FURNITURE_H__
#define __FURNITURE_H__

#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Furniture
{
private:
    string name;
    float price;
    int stock;
public:
    void print()const;
    virtual void printSpec()const =0;

public:
    Furniture(string name = "", float price = 0.0f, int stock = 0);
    virtual ~Furniture();
};

#endif


Furniture::Furniture(string name, float price, int stock)
{
    this->name=name;
    this->price=price;
    this->stock=stock;
}

Furniture::~Furniture(){}

void Furniture::print()const
{
    cout<<"All furnitures in memory:"<<endl;
    this->printSpec();
}


#ifndef __BOOKCASE_H__
#define __BOOKCASE_H__

#include "Furniture.h"

class Bookcase : Furniture
{
private:
    string material;
    float height;
public:
    Bookcase(string, float, int, string, float);
    virtual ~Bookcase();
    virtual void printSpec()const;
};

#endif

#include "Bookcase.h"

Bookcase::Bookcase(string name, float price, int stock, string material, float height) : Furniture(name, price, stock)
{
    this->material = material;
    this->height = height;
}

Bookcase::~Bookcase(){}

void Bookcase::printSpec()const
{
    cout<<material<<", "<<height<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to write `this->` everywhere

Comment: @Salgar: He does in the place he's used it (due to not using the ctor-initialiser properly). Besides, there's a school of thought that says it's good style. I don't hold an opinion on that either way.

Comment: Don't use [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `__FURNITURE_H__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update

```
class Bookcase : Furniture
```

to

```
class Bookcase : public Furniture
```

By default, C++ is private inherited,  which is makes `Bookcase has a Furniture`.

When you add `public inheritance`, it makes `Bookcase is a Furniture`

Answer (score 2):

You are using private rather than public inheritance, so the conversion is not implicit.

You have to write:

```
class Bookcase : public Furniture
//               ^^^^^^
```

This is like for members, which are private by default unless you say `public`.

If `Bookcase` where declared with the `struct` keyword, the default would have been public.

Also, you'd be much better off with an `std::vector` rather than this dangerous memory management.

Answer (score 1):

With `Furniture**` it is dangerous to use `this->furniture[this->nrOfFurniture] = ...`  because it seems to me that you do not check if there is a maximum number of `Furniture`'s that can be inserted in it (you might overwrite memory yo do not own). It is better to have a `std::vector` where you `push_back` elements.